# bazel coverage omits some files

Tags: c++, bazel

I am using `bazel coverage` to check the code test coverage, but Bazel did not include some files in the statistics, so the displayed coverage is inaccurate. How can I set it up to make Bazel include all `.h` and `.cc` files when count coverage? I checked similar questions on StackOverflow, none of them can solve this problem. The command I use is as follows:

```
bazel coverage  \
   --instrument_test_targets \
  --experimental_cc_coverage \
  --combined_report=lcov  --nocache_test_results  \
 coverage_report_generator=@bazel_tools//tools/test/CoverageOutputGenerator/java/com/google/devtools/coverageoutputgenerator:Main \
  //...
```

Another strange thing is that for code files included in final coverage report, a lot code lines and functions which are not tested in unittestare are not marked in report, they're ignored by coverage check tool.

Comment: Can you come up with some example that shows that code coverage is not working as expected - maybe you can use some open source Bazel project (e.g. https://github.com/Vertexwahn/FlatlandRT) to show that wrong test covarege is produced.